# Calculating maxima and minima of $f(x)=3^{x-1}+e^{-x+1}$

Tags: calculus

Find the minimum value of the function $f(x)=3^{x-1}+e^{-x+1}$.

I tried to use the concept of differentiation to locate the minima of the function but failed. Please help.

Comment: What did you obtain as your derivative?

Comment: It is not clear that there is a 'nice' solution. Are you sure you have the correct function?

Comment: You probably have the wrong derivative, as this one is easily obtained with the correct derivative.

Comment: Yep, the correct derivative becomes a substraction of positive values

Comment: The given function both parts are deceasing monotonously. Maybe you want maximum of  $ e^ {(x - 1)} - 3^ {(x - 1)}? $

Answer (score 1):

If you have $$f(x)=3^{x-1}+e^{1-x}$$ $$f'(x)=3^{x-1} \log (3)-e^{1-x}$$ $$f''(x)=e^{1-x}+3^{x-1} \log ^2(3)$$ The first derivative cancels when $$3^{x-1} \log (3)=e^{1-x}$$ Taking logarithms and grouping terms leads to $f'(x)=0$ when $$x=\frac{1-\log \left(\frac{\log (3)}{3}\right)}{1+\log (3)}\approx 0.955186$$ For this value, you would find that $f(x)\approx 1.99779$ and $f''(x)\approx 2.19480$ so it is a minimum.

**Edit**

When you notice that the extremum is quite close to $x=1$, you could approximate the function by its Taylor expansion built at this point; limited to the first two terms, this would give $$f(x)=2+(x-1) (\log (3)-1)+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2 \left(1+\log
   ^2(3)\right)+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ The quadratic function goes through a minimum for $$x=\frac{2+\log ^2(3)-\log (3)}{1+\log ^2(3)}\approx 0.955317$$ and at this point the approximation gives $$f(x)=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\log (3)}+\log (3)}\approx 1.99780$$

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$ \frac{df}{dx} = 3^{x-1}ln 3 - e^{-x+1} = 0$$
$$ 3^{x-1}ln3 = e^{-x+1}$$
$$ (x-1)ln(3ln3) = -x+1 $$